# kendo ui upload validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am trying to validate if the user click Import button while no file being selected and if the user select non csv file. Please advise,it currently it does not validate on anything. Even i have place the validation onSubmit button. Please advise, thank you

here is the code:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:12px; background-color:#3399FF" })     
                .Name("FileUpload")
                .Multiple(false)
                .Events(ev => ev.Success("onSuccess"))
    )

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {

 $(".k-button.k-upload-button").after(' <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Import" style="height:31px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" />');

$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e){

            var theFileElement = document.getElementById("FileUpload");
            filename = theFileElement.value;

            if(filename.length == 0)
            {
                alert("Please select a csv file to import");
                return false;
            }
            else if (!/\.csv$/i.test(filename)) {
                alert("Please upload csv file only");
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        });



});




</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict file types from uploading you can try and use the approach covered in [this forum thread](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/upload/restrict-file-types.aspx).

Keep in mind that some of the metadata may not be exposed by older browsers.

Comment: Hi Petur, what if the user not select value then click submit button. because the one in the post work only file type. thx